# Bi-Direction Synchronization of Offline App (Windows, Filtering, Embedded DB)

Tags: .net, windows, filtering, replication, offline

We are developing an application which has a locally installed component (windows service + UI, interacts with local hardware) which synchronizes its data with an Azure cloud based application (centralizes data, provides reporting/etc). The local component must be able to function offline (for as much as a week at remote sites with no connectivity). In addition, a site may have more than one PC hosting the application, and each of those local application instances must stay in sync with one another *even when they are disconnected from the cloud application*.

- We expect between 10 to 100 sites per enterprise, with as many as 10 local application installs at each.
- We are primarily .NET/C# developers.
- Filtering is applied at the record level, and is required mainly to allow provisioning new sites/machines over sometimes limited WAN connections, and reduce the amount of data transferred and stored at a site on an ongoing basis.
- We would prefer to stick with Azure/SQL Azure/.NET.

I have been looking at various options, but all seem to fall short:

- MS Sync Framework seems to have been abandoned (am I wrong? no SQL Compact 4 support?). Also, it seems to have some constraints around filtering, seems quite opaque in terms of monitoring it and fixing problems, and has possible issues with knowledge fragmentation when filtering is applied.
- Non-MS embedded relational databases either provide no synchronization mechanism, ones limited to hub-and-spoke, or seem to have had no updates in a year (e.g. empress).
- No-SQL databases (and I'll admit I have only looked at about 20 of them, and then only superficially) seem to be more focused on distributing the data and query load, rather than actually replicating the data across all nodes. I could not find any that would allow synchronization between peers on the LAN when they are disconnected from the WAN.

Even ignoring the desire to keep peers on a LAN synchronized when disconnected from the cloud, I was unable to find any embedded database that supports record-level filtered synchronization from .NET/Azure.

Has anyone tackled a similar problem and found a solution? Would it make sense to build  our own solution in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end decided to approach the problem differently. Basically it amounts to:

- Minimize the amount of data we need to sync by keeping as many operations as possible as online-only.
- Where possible pass just pass data in one direction (i.e. either generated at the site and passed up to the cloud, or generated in the cloud and sent the site).
- For the remainder where we need the data to supported necessary offline functionality and have genuine two-way sync, use an event-source model and exchange events between site and cloud when online.
- Sites immediately apply events to their data, and will keep only keep copies of events which they have not yet been able to pass to the cloud.
- The cloud application will track what the last event sent to each site was and start from that point when the site connects. It orders all events based on the order it receives them.
- The cloud generates resolving events for any conflicts it detects (which should be rare in any case).

Not what we had in mind originally, and not without its own challenges and drawbacks. But it seems like out best option to move forward.